# Is it possible to prevent ogr2ogr from generating a shapefile if no records are returned from the given intersection?

Tags: geometry, gis, gdal, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I am generating shapefiles from a geodatabase file with ogr2ogr via the spatialite dialect using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ./clipped.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ST_Intersects(SHAPE, GeomFromText('POLYGON ((46.93 -17.48, 46.91 -17.55, 47.01 -17.56, 47.01 -17.46, 46.93 -17.48))'))" ./geodatabase_file.gdb
```

The command itself works exactly as expected - returning only the records that are intersected by the given spatial query.

There are however, times when no records are returned by the intersection. When this happens empty shapefiles are generated that contain no entries. Is there a way to prevent ogr2ogr from generating files if no records are returned from a provided intersection?

Comment: I stumbled upoon the same problem, and I am now wondering if it would be possible to use the `CASE` function in the SQL so for example it would give an error if there are no records in the selection. In this case the shell would return an error, but would continue running if there were several exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that this is not possible as `ogr2ogr` creates a shapefile first and then adds features to it as it finds them. Instead it is possible to use the `ogrinfo` command to determine the `Feature Count` of the shapefile and then act accordingly.

```
ogrinfo -so -al ./geodatabase_file.gdb
```

Information for this answer came from a comment posted on this question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366599/is-it-possible-to-prevent-ogr2ogr-from-generating-a-shapefile-if-no-records-are